# Windows batch replace last found substring

Tags: windows, cmd

I faced with problem using windows cmd. I need found and replace last found substring. For instance I have a string - `@192.168.0.1:1521:SID`. I need to replace the last colon with a slash and recieve  `@192.168.0.1:1521/SID`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a fairly well defined format: IPAddress:Number:SID, so this could be treated as replacing the 2nd : with a /

```
@echo off
set val=@192.168.0.1:1521:SID
for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=:" %%a in ("%val%") do set newval=%%a:%%b/%%c
echo %newval%
yourcommand %newval%
```

Comment: Great! Please remember to accept this answer to close out this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize if the format is always the same (e.g. always the 4th char from the end) but as a general solution I would code it like below.

```
set result=
set left=
set right=@192.168.0.1:1521:SID

:loop
call :sub1 "%right%"
if %result% equ 1 goto :loop

@echo %left%/%right%
goto :eof




:sub1
for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%i in ("%~1") do (
    if ["%%j"]==[""] (
        set /a result=0
        goto :eof
    )

    if ["%left%"]==[""] (
        set left=%%i
    ) else (
        set left=%left%:%%i
    )

    set /a result=1
    set right=%%j
)
goto :eof
```

Explanation:

The code in sub1 splits the argument on the first colon from the left unless there is no colon in the argument - in this case it sets the result to 0 and returns. 
The left part is added to the left-variabel, the right part is set to the right-variable.

The main loop calls the sub sub1 until there is no more split and you're done.

Comment: Thanks for the full answer!